# Updated package is deploying through jenkins building

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, build

i updated dapper 2.0.30 to 2.0.35 and added reference from package.config in solution.when i gave jenkins build i am getting the following exception.

ResolveAssemblyReferences:
Primary reference "Dapper, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2081,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Dapper, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Could you please let me know how to fix the above warning so that i can refer to updated package.After build still old reference i am founding in package.config.
Not sure where we are copying the updated dll from local/nuget to packages folder in QA Environment.i also tried by updating the primary refernce to 2.0.30  and hint path as 2.0.35.